# How do you make a block of code that contains return statements into a function?

Tags: java, function, design-patterns

If I have a similar block of code that is used in many places with different functionality but contains return statements, how can I restructure it to make this block into a function? For example, lets say I have an object `Mailman` that contains a validity code (success/fail/reason for failure) and also possibly a package to give the callee.

In one case the mailman might just grab his item that's held and give it to the callee:

```
Mailman mailman = requestMailForPerson(person);

switch(mailman.getStatus()){
   case SUCCESS:
      Mail mail = (Mail)mailman.getHeldItem();
      return Response.ok().entity(mail).build();
   case PERSON_DOESNT_EXIST:
      return Response.status(Response.status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
   case MAIL_SERVICE_FAILED_SOMEWHERE:
      return Response.status(Response.status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
}
```

But in another he might be rerouting a letter

```
Mailman mailman = rerouteLetterForPerson(letter, person);

switch(mailman.getStatus()){
   case SUCCESS:
      Letter letter = (Letter)mailman.getHeldItem();
      if(distance(letter.address, currentLocation) > 50){
          sendToNextoffice(letter);
          return Response.ok.entity("in transit").build();
      }else{
          return Response.ok().entity(letter).build();
      }

   case PERSON_DOESNT_EXIST:
      return Response.status(Response.status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
   case MAIL_SERVICE_FAILED_SOMEWHERE:
      return Response.status(Response.status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
}
```

There are just blocks of code that look really similar, and I want to break out this logic somewhere, but handling the different success/fail scenarios is giving me a hard time.

Comment: Are there some `()` missing after `ok` in `Response.ok.entity("in transit")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have "half" of your answer in your code:

```
Mailman mailman = requestMailForPerson(person);
```

vs.

```
Mailman mailman = rerouteLetterForPerson(letter, person);
```

The key point here is: those should not be the "same" Mailman class objects. Mailman could be an **interface** and your methods return different implementations of that!

And then you just call a method like

```
mailman.doYourJob();
```

and you get the correct result; depending on the underlying implementation code!

You are fully correct in the sense that such *switch on internal status* code has a very **bad** smell. It violates the [Tell Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle. That is the part that you really want to avoid: you do **not** want to *externalize* that status, and have other "external" code make decisions based on that!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a flag to your function that states whether or not to check the distance:

```
bool checkStatus(Mailman& toCheck, bool checkDistance)
{
   switch(toCheck.getStatus()){
   case SUCCESS:
      Letter letter = (Letter)mailman.getHeldItem();
      if(checkDistance && distance(letter.address, currentLocation) > 50){
          sendToNextoffice(letter);
          return Response.ok.entity("in transit").build();
      }else{
          return Response.ok().entity(letter).build();
      }

      case PERSON_DOESNT_EXIST:
          return Response.status(Response.status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
      case MAIL_SERVICE_FAILED_SOMEWHERE:
          return Response.status(Response.status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }

}
```

Then you have use-case 1:

```
Mailman mailman = requestMailForPerson(person);
return checkStatus(mailman, false);
```

And use-case 2:

```
Mailman mailman = rerouteLetterForPerson(letter, person);
return checkStatus(mailman, true);
```

Comment: Most often, such flags are an indication of "OO design" ... done wrong or missing completely. Like here. And using **booleans** is even worse. But using an enum instead wouldn't be much better either.

Comment: @GhostCat yeah I was thinking we just have a bad design right now. We have what we call a "Payload" that handles error cases (or returns the requested object) that is more or less our hacky version of Exceptions (at the time no one on the team wanted to throw exceptions because of the whole "exceptions are for exceptional cases only" debate), but I think I will have to replace the "Payload" with exceptions because the codebase just looks cluttered and stupid right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce code duplication and make the code a bit more readable, a callback function might be a viable option. Just "tell" the method what to do in the `SUCCESS` case.

```
public process(Mailman mailman, Function<Mailman, Object> onSuccess) {
    switch (mailman.getStatus()) {
    case SUCCESS:
        return Response.ok().entity(onSuccess.apply(mailman)).build();
    case PERSON_DOESNT_EXIST:
        return Response.status(Response.status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    case MAIL_SERVICE_FAILED_SOMEWHERE:
        return Response.status(Response.status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

When calling the function, just pass in the callback as an anonymous function or even just a method reference:

```
process(requestMailForPerson(person), Mailman::getHeldItem);

process(rerouteLetterForPerson(theLetter, person),
        mailman -> {
            Letter letter = (Letter) mailman.getHeldItem();
            if (distance(letter.address, currentLocation) > 50){
                sendToNextoffice(letter);
                return "in transit";
            } else {
                return letter;
            }
        });
```